# How to access the instance variable of an object stored in linkedlist collection?

Tags: java, generics, collections

I am working on collections and generics. In my assignment, I have to store a person object into linked-list collection. Then I have to compare the age of person with value I given. But I am unable to access the variable of objects that stored in linked-list.

Here is my code:

```
class person {
    int age;
    person(int a)
    {
       age = a;
    }
    public int getAge()
    {
         return age;
    }
}

class myList<E>
{
  LinkedList<E> list;
  myList()
  {
    list = new LinkedList<E>();
  }
  void addElement(Person p){}
  void removeElement(int index){}
  boolean compareAge(int age){
       for(E p : list){
             int a = p.getAge();
             if(a.equals(age))
             {
                return true;
             }
             else{
                return false;
             }
       }
  }

}
```

but, I am getting error that is :
error: cannot find symbol
    p.getAge();
                                  ^
  symbol:   method get(int)
  location: variable value of type E
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class myList

Comment: Why make the class generic when you will only use a `Person` object? It's giving this error because `getAge()` is not defined in `Object`, which is the only acceptable type since this is a generic. There is no information about the type available otherwise

Comment: should have person instead of E see my answer ;-)

Comment: Thank you all, Now its working now, I removed the generics i.e, E. I replaced E with Person in LinkedList Declaration. I am really thank all again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E is a generic type.
Since you already know beforehand the type you wanna store in your list, your decleration should be:

```
class myList
{
  LinkedList< person > list;

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code says "take a `List` of any type, call it `E`". You are then forcing assumptions about `E` into the code, this cannot work, as `E` can be *anything*.

You either need to remove the generic declaration, so that you have a `List<person>`. Or you can restrict your `List` to hold only `person` or its children:

```
class myList<E extends person>
```

**NOTE**

Please use Java naming conventions, classes are in UpperCamelCase.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
class myList<E extends Person>
```

Also you have to fix some others issues (equals on int, and 'p' on class Person).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of E you should have person.
Linkedlist  list ...

But also I think it's not important do the whole class generic. 

[DOCUMENTATION to the list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)